# Imgproc.FindContours doesnt fill List<MatOfPoint> of Contours Opencv Android

Tags: android, opencv, xamarin, transform, perspective

i'm using OpenCV 2.4.11 for Android(Xamarin).I'm trying to do detect rect object(Paper sheet) and to make wrapPerspective,smiliar  this [tutorial](http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/automatic-perspective-correction-for-quadrilateral-objects/) but for Android, like this steps :
 Canny edge -> Largest contour -> largest rectangle -> find corners -> perspective change.

```
using (Bitmap _img = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(App._file.Path))
            {
                if (_img != null)
                {
                    m = new Mat();
                    grayM = new Mat();

                    Utils.BitmapToMat(_img, m);
                    //apply filter
                    Imgproc.Canny(m, m, 100, 100,3,true);
                    //gaus Blur
                    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(m,m,new Org.Opencv.Core.Size(5,5),5);
                    //list for contours
                    List<MatOfPoint> Contours = new List<MatOfPoint>();
                    Mat hierarcy = new Mat();
                   //our method to find contours,via filling List(Contours)
                    Imgproc.FindContours(m , Contours, hierarcy, Imgproc.RetrList, Imgproc.ChainApproxSimple);

                    System.Console.WriteLine(Contours.Count + " Contours founded");
                   //Dont know why,but Contours list is always empty(no values)
                    if (Contours.Count != 0)
                    {
                        MatOfPoint temp = Contours[0];
                    }
}
```

I'm stuck here, because i don't understand why this method(Imgproc.FindContours) doesnt fill my list of contours(always empty).

Also strange glitch:
this is an source image #1
[image: Source Image]
if i using only these methods **Imgproc.Canny** and **Imgproc.GaussianBlur** then result is like this(contours marked well)
[image: Canny with GaussianBlur]

otherwise,when i add **Imgproc.FindContours**,result is worst than w/o this method(and as i said,doesnt fill my list of contours):
[image: With Imgproc.FindContours]

Another image source #2:
[image: Source Image 2]
w/o **Imgproc.FindContours**(only **Imgproc.Canny** with **Imgproc.GaussianBlur**) :
[image: w/o FindContours]
with **FindContours** method :
[image: with Contours]

Dont understand where is my ***mistake***. Can someone explain for me,where i doing wrong OR how can i achieve my goal?
Any help will be appreciated,thanks!

Comment: It works for me if you use a JavaList<MatOfPoint>, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635635/opencv-findcontours-finds-no-contours-on-android

Comment: @Bjm hi,grats. As i have explained on my answer,i have implemented in native mode(Java) and then binded to my Xamarin project.
Anyway,thanks for your comment and ill test with JavaList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending too much time,my conclusion that is ***BUG***,because this method doesn't ported well(dunno why).
You can try to re-install new version(for e.g. Opencv 3.0.0) or implement in native mode(Java) and then bind in your MonoProject.
Enjoy !

Comment: When you say it doesn't port well, have you tried this with exact same image on other platform?  My experience with findContours() is that it requires a lot of preprocessing (tender love and care) to find the right contours you're expecting.  I've had to do lots of steps like canny, blurring, dilution, erosion, binary thresholding, sharpening etc.  Sometimes even HSV color processing to find an image that will produce the right contours.  I believe the findContours() method also has some parameters for tweaking what it finds.

Comment: @medloh yes,i tried on exact same image on native platform and it's works fine. Problem was with bad port to C# version :).

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to the same issue. I found that the solution was to use a JavaList for the contours list.

reference: https://github.com/TrekDev/Xamarin.Android.OpenCV/issues/1